# "Time needed to complete a work" -- is this correct?

Tags: american-english

Is the usage of "a work" correct here? My supervisor, who is not an English teacher, advised me to use "a task" instead.

Usually, though, I would not mind either way. Does somebody have another opinion?

Comment: You almost certainly mean **task**.  Simple!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct.

However, in my experience, *a work* is generally used to describe a piece of art.

Comment: Indeed. "Work" is countable only in special senses (such as works of art).

Comment: You could say, "a piece of work" rather than "a work".

Comment: Or just "time needed to complete work," that what I would likely expect/use; see also business-y constructions like "statement of work," [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_of_work ]  etc.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you’re trying to say, but it’s **probably not correct**.

First the more common situation: if you are (for instance) a student doing essays, or a mechanic working on cars, then the phrase you gave would not be correct.  Instead, you could say something like

> time needed to complete work

or

> time needed to complete a task

or *…this work*, *…the work*, *…my work*, etc., depending on context. You can have one task but you can't have one 'work' (that sounds really wrong like 'one water').

A less common (but perfectly OK usage),  'work' as a count noun is typically only used for works of art.  So if you are an artist explaining how long it takes you to finish a painting, then yes, you could talk about *time needed to complete a work*.

But that phrase standing alone without context sounds wrong.