# What makes this sentence 'clunky'?

Tags: grammar, phrasing

I've had comments that the sentence below seems awkward and clunky. Can anyone help me clarify what it is that is off about it. Background being:

"An issue has been found but not correcting in this report (piece of work). Thus, ..."

> It is my recommendation that a future work look at this.

These alternatives were suggested, however I can't shake that the above sentence is OK.

> It is my recommendation that a future piece of work looks at this.
>
> It is my recommendation that future work looks at this.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you clarify a) your personal dialect of English and b) the dialect of English used by those who are commenting that your sentence is clunky? Based on the discussions on the answers below, one source of clunkiness may be the difference between American English and British English.

Comment: Sure. (a) British (b) Also British. Although, it might be worth considering the masses of American English material consumed online?

Comment: Aha! Well that does help. I've incorporated that into my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Time needed to complete a work" -- is this correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25898/time-needed-to-complete-a-work-is-this-correct)

Comment: Perhaps you could use 'treat' instead of 'work': "...that a future work treats this in more detail,"

Comment: Your "recommendation" is clunky because it is a very weak and useless-sounding statement:  "we found a problem but didn't fix it; I recommend that eventually, perhaps somebody should do something about it."   It seems to me that what you really want to say is that someone (the client?) needs to be aware of the issue so that they can make sure that it gets fixed.

Comment: Agreed, note there is more context to this that I left out. My concern was the grammar/word choice only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making *work* countable, with "...a future work..."

*Work* **can** be countable, and it does mean a discrete and identifiable result of work, but it is usually applied to musical works and the like.

> The Choral Symphony is one of Beethoven's most popular works.
>   A particular work I like is the *St Matthew Passion* by the Pet Shop Boys or whoever.

Where the discrete and identifiable piece of work is not an artistic composition, you might use ***job***.

> It is my recommendation that a future job looks at this.

Where *work* simply involves working, then it's a mass (uncountable) noun.

> It is my recommendation that future work looks at this.

Comment: Although I know that’s grammatical for you, on this side of the pond those verbs need to be *look*.

Comment: @tchrist - and which side of the pond is "this" side...?

Comment: @AndyT BrE is generally fine without using the "subjunctive" in such sentences (it works, but it's fussy). AmE generally requires it.

Comment: @tchrist *look* is 'right' here, it's just not ordinary anymore.  Is it really standard US speak?

Comment: @Dan Yes, it really is.

Comment: 'Need to be' and 'is required' sound prescriptive. Would a Brit or other indicative-chooser be arrested in the US? CGEL, often taken to be the final arbiter, states that the indicative is a grammatical choice: 'In[these] cases the subjunctive construction [is not] obligatory.' [Section 7.1]

Answer (score 5):

I believe that your sentence is grammatically acceptable. But it is indeed "clunky"; it doesn't parse well. I had to read it two or three times to comprehend that it was indeed grammatically correct.

---

Personally, I think this clunkiness stems from the use of "work" as a countable noun. Though you can have "a work", it is more normal for it to be qualified as a particular type, e.g. "a work of art" or "the works of Shakespeare".

Normally when I hear the phrase "future work" I see it as an uncountable noun: there is a lot of work to be done; it will be done in the future; there is a lot of future work.

---

*Look* vs *Looks* - The former is a subjunctive mood and is required in the US. Either are acceptable in Britain, though the latter is far more common. With your audience being British, *look* is certainly a little unusual, and could be taken as "clunky". Certainly, as a native Brit, I would use *looks* in this situation.

---

My personal recommendation for your sentence is:

> It is my recommendation that this is looked at in the future.

This a) avoids using "future work" as a countable noun, and b) is definitely an acceptable form of the verb *to look*.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. But I would use "this (should) be looked at" as there is "recommendation". What do you think?

Comment: @Rathony - As per [A.P.'s](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/281563/91730) link, [the *should* is optional](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/recommend). Apparently it's more common to include it in British English. Although I am British, I wouldn't put it in here. Then again, I wouldn't object to it being here. It's a bit 50:50 really.

Comment: That's why I liked your answer. A subjunctive mood usage seems to be controversial.

Comment: Note that in the US we'd use "that this be looked at," since there's an implicit _should_.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the intention and context correctly, try this:

> The current report contains an unaddressed issue. I recommend that a
>   future version of the report should address it.

[The *should* is optional.](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/recommend)

Some of the inelegance in your sentence perhaps comes from the fact that it mixes formal and informal language. *It is my recommendation* is formal, but *look* sounds colloquial.

Comment: (+1) In terms of style, I much prefer 'I recommend' over the 'business-speak 'version,  "It is my recommendation'  -- Kill the jargon!

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question. The question isn't so much "what's a good way of phrasing this" as it is "why are people objecting to the way I phrased this?"

Comment: Wasn't quite the answer i wanted but I hadn't thought about the mix of formal/informal before, thanks for this input.

Comment: @AndyT Note that I do try to explain why other people might say the OP's sentence is inelegant.

Comment: @A.P. - Hmm, granted. It is rather tacked on the end as an afterthought rather than being your main answer though.

Answer (score 1):

There are already good answers that address "work" as countable/uncountable.
The sentence is also clunky because "future work" is the subject of the verb "look" - as if the work is doing the looking.  It would feel more natural to say that future work could address or correct an issue, rather than look at it.  It's the people doing the future work who will be looking.

Answer (score 1):

> Background: *An issue has been found but not **correcting** in this report.*
>
> - *It is my recommendation that a future **work** look at this.*

First, the background sentence is ungrammatical. It should be "***corrected***", not *correcting*.

Second, *work* can't be used this way to refer to a single non-artistic event;
if it were a painting or a novel instead of a report, you could call it ***a** work*.
But if it's not artistic, *work* is mass, not count. A better choice would be to repeat *report*.

- *It is my recommendation that a future **report** look at this.*

Answer (score 0):

I think the original sentence is a fine example of the English subjunctive, and whoever called it "clunky" was wrong. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive

Answer (score 0):

"An issue has been found but not correcting in this report (piece of work). Thus, ..."

```
It is my recommendation that a future work look at this."
```

You don't think that's clunky? It's very clunky and bordering on unreadable... too long, subjunctive passive tense, correcting has no verb tense to match "has been", unneeded parentheses, and the coup de gras, future work can't "look". Also, it doesn't say anything useful, so it can't have good grammar.

An [type of issue] issue was found but not fixed in the current [release/work/foo]. This issue is being [tracked/addressed by x] and should be remedied before the next [release/work/foo.]